# Partida de Mus Online

Tags: java

Estamos implementando una partida de mus online, en Java, para la cual hemos creado varias clases: `Jugador`, `Carta`, `Mesa` y `Partida`. En esta última estamos atascados en cómo crear los métodos del juego del mus, como son el turno de Grande, Pequeña...

En esta clase, tenemos una `List<Jugador> jugadores = new ArrayList<>();` donde están incluidos los 4 jugadores y cada uno tiene 4 cartas, ya ordenas de mayor a menor puntuación.

No se si alguien nos pudiera echar una mano.
Ahí os dejo el código de partida hasta el momento

```
public class Partida {

List<Jugador> lJugadores = null;
Mesa m1 =null;

public Partida()
{
    for(int i = 0;i<4;i++)
    {
        this.lJugadores.add(new Jugador());
    }

     m1 = new Mesa();
}

public void iniciarPartida()
{
    for(Jugador j : this.lJugadores)
    {
        j.obtenerCartaInicial(m1);
    }
}

public void mus()
{
    boolean b = true;
    while(b)
    {

        //Comprobamos si quiere mus ( 1-4) o no quieren (0)
        int [] numCartas = new int[4];
        int n = 0;
        for(Jugador j : this.lJugadores)
        {
            j.mostrarCartas();
            numCartas[n] = j.quiereMus();

        }


        int i = 0;
        while(i<4 && b==true)
        {
            if(numCartas[i]==0)
            {
                b = false;
            }
            i++;
        }
        //Si hay mus
        if(b)
        {   
            Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
            for(Jugador j : this.lJugadores)
            {
                j.mostrarCartas();
                System.out.println("¿Qué cartas quieres quitarte? [0-3]");

                for(int i2 =0; i2<numCartas[i2];i++)
                {
                    int posicion = entrada.nextInt();
                    Carta c = j.cartas.remove(posicion);
                    this.m1.añadirCartaMontonMus(c);
                    if(!this.m1.montonVacio())
                    {
                        j.cartas.add(posicion, this.m1.getCartaMonton());
                    }
                    else {
                        j.cartas.add(posicion, this.m1.getCartaMus());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

public void cambiarMano()
{
    Jugador j1 = this.lJugadores.get(0);
    this.lJugadores.remove(j1);
    this.lJugadores.add(j1);
}
```

Comment: miraste [ask]? no queda claro que estas preguntando. Necesitas que alguien te escriba esa clase? o donde esta el problema?

Comment: Si, necesitaría alguna ayuda para seguir con esa clase, con métodos como grande o pequeña, agún consejo, código o algo

Comment: Ni consejo ni codigo te podemos brindar. Es tu ejercicio, y aca no hacemos ejercicios a menos que demuestres que intetaste algo. Que problema hay en crear una clase de Juego, y que ella dicte las reglas del juego?

Comment: Quizá lo más sencillo sea implementar una máquinta de estados. El juego tiene 6 fases:  repartición de cartas, las 4 rondas de envides y el resultado final. Podrías crear un flujo de trabajo en el que se vayan consumiendo fases para cada ronda, y luego repetir las rondas hasta que una pareja gane el juego